# How to read a .txt in Pandas that isn't properly delimited

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, delimiter

I have a .txt file that is very similar to a .csv, but not quite. As you can see the first 4 columns could be delimited with a space, but the last string would be split into a varying amount of columns. I need the last string to be just one column.

```
09 4 10/11/2021 22:21:17 The PLC reported that sorter SS02 has E-stopped.
08 4 10/11/2021 22:21:17 The PLC reported that sorter SS02 has stopped.
08 4 10/11/2021 22:21:18 The PLC reported that sorter SS01 has stopped.
20 5 10/11/2021 22:21:18 The PLC reported that purge mode was disabled for sorter SS02.
20 5 10/11/2021 22:21:18 The PLC reported that purge mode was disabled for sorter SS01.
23 5 10/11/2021 22:21:19 AUX Sortation has been enabled for sorter SS02.
23 5 10/11/2021 22:21:20 AUX Sortation has been enabled for sorter SS01.
```

How can I read this in so I have just 5 consistent columns? I will probably combine date and time into one column later.

Comment: if your text file is always generated the same, you could split on the first 4 spaces. s.split(" ", 4) can split up to a max number (currently 4) which you could do per new line.

Comment: You could try reading it as a fixed width data file and use `pandas.read_fwf` with `colspecs = [(0, 2), (2, 4), (4, 24), (24, 100)]` or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pre-parse each line and then create the DataFrame, for example:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('input.txt') as f_input:
    data = [line.strip().split(' ', 4) for line in f_input]
        
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['c1', 'c2', 'date', 'time', 'desc'])
print(df)
```

Giving you:

```
   c1 c2        date      time                                                            desc
0  09  4  10/11/2021  22:21:17                The PLC reported that sorter SS02 has E-stopped.
1  08  4  10/11/2021  22:21:17                  The PLC reported that sorter SS02 has stopped.
2  08  4  10/11/2021  22:21:18                  The PLC reported that sorter SS01 has stopped.
3  20  5  10/11/2021  22:21:18  The PLC reported that purge mode was disabled for sorter SS02.
4  20  5  10/11/2021  22:21:18  The PLC reported that purge mode was disabled for sorter SS01.
5  23  5  10/11/2021  22:21:19                 AUX Sortation has been enabled for sorter SS02.
6  23  5  10/11/2021  22:21:20                 AUX Sortation has been enabled for sorter SS01.
```

A datetime column could be added by combining the `date` and `time` columns and converting them into a datetime:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'])
```

Comment: Perfect solution, thank you!